# New to Programming: Python Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I keep getting a Syntax error when I type:

```
def someFunction(a, b):
    print(a+b)
someFunction(12, 451)
```

then it says:

```
File"<stdin>", line 3
           someFunction()
                 Syntax Error
```

I really appreciate any guidance! Thank you so much!
(I am using Python 2.7.5)

Answer (score 3):

If I had to guess, you are in the Python interpreter and wrote this:

```
>>> def someFunction(a, b):
...     print(a+b)
... someFunction(12, 451)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    someFunction(12, 451)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

You need to put one more newline after the `print` line:

```
>>> def someFunction(a, b):
...     print(a+b)
...
>>> someFunction(12, 451)
463
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the interactive interpreter, you need one more newline after a block.

Only put *new* expressions or statements on the next `>>>` prompt:

```
>>> def someFunction(a, b):
...     print(a+b)
... 
>>> someFunction(12, 451)
463
```

Here, I hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on the empty `...` line to 'close' the function.